# Adding a comment column to a filtered data and make it linked to the correct record

Tags: google-sheets

I'm not sure if this can be done with filter function or even with google sheets, I have two sheets, one that have the raw data, and these data is always updated and each record has an if statement, the other sheet is filtered based on the condition column, it also has a comment column. The problem is if some one puts a comment and then the data changed and the if statement updates the condition column then the filtered sheet will be updated but the comment column will not, and so the wrong comment will be linked to the wrong record.

Here is an example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gOFqqsVMozd4IotZlH4AMDxtMdmeBqpDMzh70VvgQ2U/edit?usp=sharing

The data shows the weight of a group of people and this will change overtime, the conditional column will check if the weight is over 200 and if true will display "Yes" otherwise "No"

The filtered sheet will filter the main sheet based on the condition when if is "Yes", so currently Mark and Alex is filtered and comments are added for both, but on the raw data sheet if someone edits Alex's weight to less than 200, then only Mark will show up but both comments will still be there and now Alex's comment will be shown as Marks comment, while Marks comment will stay on an empty filtered row.

Is there's a way to link the comments to correct enteries?

Thanks

Comment: It seems that this is not possible using the current options available in Google Sheets. Apps Script could be used to run a time based trigger to match the comment to a unique identifier and update its location as needed, I can try creating code for that if it's OK for you.

Comment: @Amr did you find a way to get this done using functions or did Bryan's solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Since I was not able to find a solution using Formulas or built-in settings I created a Google Apps Script code that would let you re-order the comments using a new menu in Google Sheets:

#### Output:

[image: Example]

#### Set up:

- In order for this to work you need to make sure that all comments begin with the exact match of its corresponding name. For example (A comment for a new name "John" would start with `John`).

  - It would also work if you create a new column and start using a different unique Identifier.
- I added a validator to cell `F1` in `Filtered data`, this will show `FALSE` if any of the comments in the list don't match to its unique identifier, this is used as an alert and for additional validation within Apps Script. You would need to update it if you decide to start using a different column to match comments.

`[google-sheets=COUNTA(A2:A)=SUM(INDEX(COUNTIF(left(D2:D,LEN(A2:A)),A2:A)))`

#### Apps Script Code:

1. On the Spreadsheet that you need to update click "Extensions" > "Apps Script".
2. Replace all the code there with the following and click "Save".

```js
const commentsSheet = "Filtered data"; //Name of the sheet where the comments are posted.
const validatorCell = "F1"; //A1 Notation where the validation is performed.
const commentColumn = "D"; // Column where the commnets are being posted.
const uniqueIdColumn = "A"; // Columns where the uniqueId is posted.

const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(commentsSheet);
const validatorRange = sheet.getRange(validatorCell);

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

function onOpen() {

  // Whe the sheet opens a new menu item is added.
  ui.createMenu('Comments')
    .addItem('Fix Comments', 'fixComments')
    .addToUi();

}

function fixComments() {

  // We'll re-arrange comments only if the validation is FALSE.
  if (!validatorRange.getValue()) {

    var ids = sheet.getRange(uniqueIdColumn + "2:" + uniqueIdColumn).getValues().flat().filter(Boolean);
    var oldValues = sheet.getRange(commentColumn + "2:" + commentColumn).getValues().flat().filter(Boolean);
    sheet.getRange(commentColumn + "2:" + commentColumn).clearContent();

    // Array where the re-arranged comments will be stored.
    var newValues = [];

    for (var i in ids) {
      var foundComment = false;
      var name = ids[i];

      // Loop through all the records to find its matching comment based on uniqueId.
      for (var j in oldValues) {
        if (name == oldValues[j].substring(0, name.length)) {
          newValues.push(oldValues.splice(j, 1));
          foundComment = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      // If no comment is found for an existing record the code prints "Missing comment" instead.
      if (!foundComment) newValues.push(["Missing comment"]);
    }

    // If there are comments with no matching uniqueId they are moved to the end of the list.
    oldValues.forEach(value => {
      if (value !== "Missing comment") {
        newValues.push([value])
      }
    }
    );
    // The re-arranged comments are re-added back.
    sheet.getRange(commentColumn + "2:" + commentColumn + (newValues.length + 1)).setValues(newValues);
    // ui.alert("All comments were re-arranged");

  } else {
    // An alert is shown if validation is TRUE
    ui.alert("All comments are in order, no need to re-arrange");
  }
}
```